# How to get data after post json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

here is my PHP code

```
$response = array();

$user1 = array();
$user1['name'] = 'Tom';
$user1['age'] = '13';

$user2 = array();
$user2['name'] = 'Jack';
$user2['age'] = '20';

$response[] = $user1;
$response[] = $user2;

echo json_encode($response);
```

and here is my .html file that use jquery to get data from PHP file like

```
$.post('file.php', {userid : '1234'}, function(data){
   alert(data) //problem here
}, 'json');
```

the problem is how to get user1's name after I use $.post in that code.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Because your user arrays are associative, they are being translated into json objects, not arrays.

access them with `data[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need JSON.parse

var response = JSON.parse(data)

Now response is your JSON object that has all the data.